Co-exist bluetooth keyboard and iPhone on screen keyboard
I am using Xcode 15 and iPhone iOS 17.  I have bluetooth barcode scanner which is activated as external keyboard.  It works on below code and iOS Notes.  I can press key and it does show on iPhone.  I want to use it to scan barcode and process it.  At the same time, I have other fields which require iPhone on screen keyboard.  I use below code to test.
On below code, Text(fromBluetooth) is for key pressed from Bluetooth keyboard.  It works.  The problem is on TextField("From iPhone on screen keyboard", text: $fromiPhone).  I tap it and iPhone keyboard does not show up.
My requirement for this testing code:

When start up, waiting for bluetooth keyboard to enter. When key press, assign to variable fromBluetooth.

When TextField is tapped and get focus, pop-up iPhone on screen keyboard and let user enter to TextField. When TextField get focus, it is better to disable bluetooth keyboard.

When user press "Return" key on iPhone keyboard TextField give up focus, hide iPhone keyboard and activate bluetooth keyboard. It is kind of go to item 1.

Bluetooth keyboard and iPhone Keyboard serve two different purpose. On my application, bluetooth keyboard is a barcode scanner. It is not data entry keyboard for TextField. I must bring up iPhone on screen keyboard for user to enter to TextField.  Thanks.


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var selectedRow: Int?
  @State private var fromiPhone: String = ""
  @State private var fromBluetooth: String = "From bluetooth keyboard"
  @FocusState private var focused: Bool

  var body: some View {
    Spacer()
    Text(fromBluetooth)
    Spacer()
    TextField("From iPhone on screen keyboard", text: $fromiPhone)
    Spacer()
    .focusable()
    .focused($focused)
    .onKeyPress { press in
      fromBluetooth = press.characters
      print(press.debugDescription)
      return .handled
    }
    .onAppear() {
      focused = true
    }
  }
}

